# PHP database timestamp format

Tags: php, html

I have a database with a attribute "DATUM". "DATUM" is a timestamp. Now i want to change the format of the timestamp. 
Here is a picture of the timestamp with the wrong format

[image]

Here with the right format, but at the wrong place

[image]

And that the problem. I dont get the "new timestamp" into a echo with the text "geschrieben von Peter am". Maybe someone of you can help me. Here is the code

```
        /* This should be in 1 echo*/
        /* Like this: 
            $d = date_create($row['DATUM']);
            echo "<a class='article-autor'>geschrieben von $row[AUTOR] am ($d->format('j.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r'))</a>";   

        But it wont work 


        Thats the real code at the moment: */
        echo "<a class='article-autor'>geschrieben von $row[AUTOR] am $row[DATUM]</a>";        
        $d = date_create($row['DATUM']);
        echo($d->format('j.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r'));
```

Comment: You need to format it using PHP and not change it in MySQL.Look at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strftime.php

Comment: you just need to remove `$row[DATUM]`.

Comment: put your `$d = date_create($row['DATUM']);$d->format('j.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r');` before your `echo "<a class='article-autor'>...` and then change `... am $row[DATUM]</a>` to `... am $d</a>`

Comment: Now my code looks like this: `$d = date_create($row['DATUM']);
        $d->format('j.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r');
        
        echo "<a class='article-autor'>geschrieben von $row[AUTOR] am $d</a>";`, but i get an error: **Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in**

Comment: Try `$d = date_create($row['DATUM']); $datum = $d->format('j.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r'); echo "<a class='article-autor'>geschrieben von $row[AUTOR] am $datum</a>";`. Save the formatted DateTime object to a var, and then echo that var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
echo "<a class='article-autor'>geschrieben von $row[AUTOR] am"."$d->format('j.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\r')"."</a>";
```

Comment: I get 2 errors... **Notice: Undefined variable: d in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\include\news.html on line 13

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\include\news.html on line 13
geschrieben von Peter am('j.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h ')**

Comment: undefined variable?? didn't you put this: $d = date_create($row['DATUM']); before the echo statement?

Comment: Yep... I deleted the statement. But it works too! :) Thanks !

Comment: Sure, thats no problem :)